# Cooley-Tukey algorithm python out of range

Tags: python, algorithm

I am analyzing the complexity of an implementation of the Cooley-Tukey algorithm, written in Python (the code was taken from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Python)):

```
def fft(x):
N = len(x)
print N, N//2
if N <= 1:
    return x
even = fft(x[0::2])
odd = fft(x[1::2])
T = [exp(-2j*pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N//2)] + [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N//2)]
```

The code works well with the example shown in the webpage; in fact, it seems to work with any list with a length <= 9. For some reason, trying with a list of length > 10:

```
print( ' '.join("%5.3f" % abs(f) for f in fft([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])))
```

returns the following error:

> ```
> T = [exp(-2j*pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Does anyone know the reason why this fails?

Answer (score 2):

The Cooley-Tukey implementation you're using assumes the input length is a power of two. Power-of-two input lengths are by far the easiest to implement Cooley-Tukey for; extending this code to non-power-of-two input lengths would require completely rewriting it.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My teacher told me that there is no problem in making such assumption, given that the main goal is to analyze the complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This is numeric error, `len(odd)<N//2`. The following code

```
try:
    T = [exp(-2j*pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
except IndexError:
    print len(odd), N
    raise
```

will prints out

```
4 10
```

which means when `N==10`, `len(odd)==4` so you got IndexError.